# I want JMenu to show the items when the program starts

Tags: java

I've created a menubar and added a menu with several items. When I do doClick() on the JMenu(archiveMenu) it highlights the button for the menu but it doesnt show any of the items that are added to it. I've tried doing doClick() before the adding of actionListeners to the items and setVisible(true) but nothing works.

I think it has something to do with the fact that they have seperate actionListeners but I'm so far in to the program that changing to a single actionListener would lead to a huge amount of work. I appreciate any help, thanks!

It looks like this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/8ca08ee94d7de7840c808a19261b762f.png]

```
// MENU BAR
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
JMenu archiveMenu = new JMenu("Archive");
menuBar.add(archiveMenu);
JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New Map");
JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load places");
JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
newItem.addActionListener(new NewMapLis());
loadItem.addActionListener(new LoadLis());
saveItem.addActionListener(new SaveLis());
exitItem.addActionListener(new ExitLis());
archiveMenu.add(newItem);
archiveMenu.add(loadItem);
archiveMenu.add(saveItem);
archiveMenu.add(exitItem);

archiveMenu.doClick();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that when `doClick()` is called the window is not fully loaded yet.

you need to perform it after loading.

for example, you could call it when the frame is opened:

```
myFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        archiveMenu.doClick();
    }

});
```

Comment: I have a windowListener but it was only for closing the program. I added the windowOpened aswell but I get the same result.

    class StopLis extends WindowAdapter {
  Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent wev) {
   stopExecution();
  }
  Override
  public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
         archiveMenu.doClick();
     }
 }

Comment: Nevermind, it works. I forgot to remove the previous archiveMenu.doClick() that was located in the constructor. Thank you very much!